# How to access a panel inside gridview from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a grid view, which contains a dropdownlist and a panel that i want to make invisible and visible by the selected value of the dropdownlist.

The javascript code which works when not used with the gridview is:

```
   function showPannel(panelId,dropdownId ) {
        var panel = document.getElementById(panelId);
        var dropDown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
        if (dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value = 'Diesel Deals') {
             panel.className = "visibleDiv";

       }
        else{
            panel.className = "hiddenDiv";
            }

    }
```

i'm passing the panelId and dropdownlist id from here:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Panel p = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("Panel1");
            DropDownList t1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            t1.Attributes.Add("onchange",
                 string.Format("javascript:showPannel('{0}', '{1}')",p.ClientID, t1.ClientID ));
        }
```

but it is not working. The function is getting called, but its giving undefined when dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value  is alerted.

I tried to do

```
                    Gridview1 = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
             var cell = Gridview1.rows[0].cells[2];
             var dropdownlist = cell.childNodes[0];
             var dropdownSelectedValue = dropdownlist.options[dropdownlist.selectedIndex].value;
             alert(dropdownSelectedValue);
```

but its not working either.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: have you tried alert in your function ans see is the id is same as it is rendering?

Comment: Are you using jquery also?

Comment: no i just checked i didn't know that i could its being rendered as MainContent_GridView1_DropDownList1_7 should i try adding the gridview client id

Comment: try to use alert in both panelId,dropdownId  and see what is the client id.

Comment: its just this part DropDownList1_7

Comment: i will try to add the client id when im adding the attribute

Comment: It will be easy if you use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Panel p = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("Panel1");
            DropDownList t1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            string p_id = GridView1.ClientID + "_" + p.ClientID;
            string ddL_id = GridView1.ClientID + "_" + t1.ClientID;
            t1.Attributes.Add("onchange",
                 string.Format("javascript:showPannel('{0}', '{1}')", p_id, ddL_id ));
```

thanks for the hint about rendering id